# How do I format a request to Google geocoder in order to get the correct response?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Note that I am loading the GoogleAPIs via:

```
  <script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=weekly&callback=initializeMaps&region=CA&key=*****" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

and that I had no problem until I changed this to "v=weekly" from "v=3.4" because Google was whining about the obsolete version.  Further note that I am explicitly indicating that I am looking for locations in Canada, not the US.

If I search for the location "camden, kent county, Ontario, Canada" on the web Google maps returns the correct result, including the boundaries of that township.

[image]

But if I send the exact same string into the geocoder API I get back the following three results, **none** of which is correct:

My code is:

```
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': searchName},
             function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results.length > 1)
            {
                alert("Location.js: geocoder returned multiple results for '" + searchName + " : " + JSON.stringify(results));  // this produces the report which is appended
                displayMap(results[1].geometry.location, zoom, searchName);
            }
            else
                displayMap(results[0].geometry.location, zoom, searchName);
```

And the alert displays:

Location.js: geocoder returned multiple results for 'Camden, Kent county, Ontario, Canada : [{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Ontario","short_name":"ON","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Canada","short_name":"CA","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Ontario, Canada","geometry":{"bounds":{"south":41.6765559,"west":-95.15617809999999,"north":56.931393,"east":-74.2608162},"location":{"lat":51.253775,"lng":-85.3232139},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"south":41.6765559,"west":-95.15617809999999,"north":56.931393,"east":-74.2608162}},"partial_match":true,"place_id":"ChIJrxNRX7IFzkwRCR5iKVZC-HA","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},

{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Camden","short_name":"Camden","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Kent County","short_name":"Kent County","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Delaware","short_name":"DE","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United States","short_name":"US","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Camden, DE, USA","geometry":{"bounds":{"south":39.085206,"west":-75.5705749,"north":39.1248111,"east":-75.532629},"location":{"lat":39.1134458,"lng":-75.5418687},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"south":39.085206,"west":-75.5705749,"north":39.1248111,"east":-75.532629}},"partial_match":true,"place_id":"ChIJc9sqjeGBuIkRLvbkTAzWM1E","types":["locality","political"]},

{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Kent County","short_name":"Kent County","types":["colloquial_area","political"]},{"long_name":"New Brunswick","short_name":"NB","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Canada","short_name":"CA","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Kent County, NB, Canada","geometry":{"bounds":{"south":46.254743,"west":-65.8516609,"north":47.480631,"east":-63.99150399999999},"location":{"lat":46.46516159999999,"lng":-65.2841777},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"south":46.254743,"west":-65.8516609,"north":47.480631,"east":-63.99150399999999}},"partial_match":true,"place_id":"ChIJZQopqoS3oUwRfvPJUlTyH_4","types":["colloquial_area","political"]}]

The first response is the entire province of Ontario, Canada!
The second response is Camden, **Delaware, USA**!
The third response is Kent County, **New Brunswick**, Canada!

How do I correct the code to get the correct response from Geocoder?

Comment: Does  `camden township, kent county, Ontario, Canada` return the correct location for you?

Comment: It does for me...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  How does my application know that that Camden, Kent, Ontario, Canada is a township?  I am already having to go to the trouble of maintaining a list of all of the counties in Ontario because the API misinterprets Camden, Kent, Ontario, Canada if I omit the qualifier "County".  Furthermore if I already know that Camden, Kent, is a township what do I need the geocoder for?  I can simply record the information in my own database or find an alternative geocoder and Google loses my busjness!

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions.  Since the request worked under v=3.4 and does not work on v=weekly. I it is ,y opini9n tyat the API is broken.  My application cannot be PSYCHIC.  All that it has is a string of text entered by a client.  I do not believe that it is reasonable to FORCE my application to do extra work because of deficiencies in the Google API.  My code has EXPLICITLY asked for a place name Camden in Kent County, Ontario, Canada.  I have also explicitly indicated that I am requesting from Canada.  Why does Google give me Camden in DELAWARE, USA?

Comment: I tried Geocoding `camden, kent county, Ontario, Canada` on my end and I'm getting a partial match. I think what I can suggest for you to use is the [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete) of Places API, as it is considered as [Best Practice](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices) to use it for ambiguous queries or for user inputs who tend to make mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of Autocomplete.  Having read the description I believe that it would only result in many more invalid responses because there are so many places in the world that start with "Camden".  I honestly believe that since I made it EXPLICITLY CLEAR TO THE API that I was looking for a location in Kent County, Ontario, Canada that the response I received, including a response from ANOTHER COUNTRY, is actually WRONG, especially since I got the correct response every time when using v=3.4.  How do I get in contact with the department at Google which is responsible?